# Is "impaled" used naturally?

Tags: word-usage

The zombie jumped up on the bar and started to run across the length of it towards Ted. The zombie reached the end of the bar and jumped, but just as it did Ted rushed forward and impaled it with the sword.

I would like to know if "impaled" is used naturally in my example?

Comment: Sounds alright.

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but I found it hard to fully understand the definition of the word and when it can be used. Can I use "impaled" if Ted thrusted the sword into the "stomach" of the zombie?

Comment: @user118626, yes, that's the most common meaning of the term, at least if you're reading sword & sorcery literature. (There's a specific meaning of *impale* for a particular way of torturing people that you shouldn't look up if you are eating or about to eat)